# Dynamic web page resizing with javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I currently have a page that is being resized through the use of javascript whenever the end-user resizes the window, so that scrolling is reduced or eliminated when not necessary.  I have a loader.js jquery file which picks out .html documents to throw in to the content section of the page when the user selects an option from the left menu:

```
$("#response").load("home.html");
$("#home").click(function(){
// load home page on click
    $("#response").load("home.html");
    setTimeout("resizefunc()",500);
});
$("#about").click(function(){
// load about page on click
$("#response").load("about.html");
    setTimeout("resizefunc()",500);
});
//etc
```

While these timeout functions work most of the time, they have the potential to fail if the page loads abnormally slow for any reason.  I am using document.ElementId.scrollHeight to determine the height of each new page, but it seems to only detect the height after the changes have been correctly applied.  If the javascript loads before the page content then the resize fails.

It seems that if I were using complete html documents for each page then the problem would be irrelevant.  I could put an onLoad event in to the body of each one and have it resize there... But since the  tag is only loaded once I'm somewhat at a loss.  My current implementation "works", but I feel that there should be something more efficient.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use onLoad, instead wrap your code in

```
$(window).load(function() {
  // your code here
});
```

Also, instead of load() with just the filename as a parameter, use:

```
$('#response').load('file.html', function() {
  resizefunc();
});
```

Comment: Changed each of the timeouts to what you listed above and it worked.  not sure why it works that way but doesn't if i simply call the resize function after the .load, but within the same click event... Either way, thanks for the quick response

Comment: no worries. it works because the second parameter in the load() function is a callback function which gets triggered after the content has loaded, no need to "guess" how long it takes for the content to load.

PS: marking answer as approved if it's a correct solution is nice too :)

Comment: Sorry, first time posting a question here :P  Marked it now.

Answer (score 1):

Along with "load" you could also use "resize" as one of the events. This would allow dynamic resizing.

```
$(window).resize(function() {
    resizefunc()
});

function resizefunc() 
{
   // code to resize.
}
```

**See:** http://api.jquery.com/resize/

Comment: I didn't realize that .resize() triggered when the page scroll length changed... I just assumed that it was only the actual window border resizing.  If that is the case, then this is also a valid answer.  I'll give it a try tomorrow when I wake up.

Comment: @Ryan Baker - yeah give it a try,generally we use both "load" and "resize" together. You could use a "css" to do the actual resize of the html content.